# how to specify launch argument type in ros2 launch command?

Tags: ros2, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a ROS2 node which takes a 'username' string argument. I can normally run the node like this:

```
ros2 launch my_pkg launch.py username:=XXX
```

In my case, my username is composed of digits only, like so:

```
ros2 launch my_pkg launch.py username:=12345
```

The issue then is that ros2 launch fails because:

```
 rclpy.exceptions.InvalidParameterTypeException: Trying to set parameter 'username' to '12345' of type 'INTEGER', expecting type 'STRING'
```

surrounding 12345 with quotes like "12345" or '12345' does not help. How can I tell ROS my argument is a String and not an integer?

This can be reproduced with this node: https://github.com/LORD-MicroStrain/ntrip_client/tree/ros2-1.2.0

```
$ ros2 launch ntrip_client ntrip_client_launch.py username:=12345
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/vrichard/.ros/log/2022-09-11-13-05-38-795894-vr-desktop-702025
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [ntrip_ros.py-1]: process started with pid [702095]
[ntrip_ros.py-1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[ntrip_ros.py-1]   File "/home/vrichard/test/install/ntrip_client/lib/ntrip_client/ntrip_ros.py", line 153, in <module>
[ntrip_ros.py-1]     node = NTRIPRos()
[ntrip_ros.py-1]   File "/home/vrichard/test/install/ntrip_client/lib/ntrip_client/ntrip_ros.py", line 26, in __init__
[ntrip_ros.py-1]     self.declare_parameters(
[ntrip_ros.py-1]   File "/opt/ros/galactic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rclpy/node.py", line 491, in declare_parameters
[ntrip_ros.py-1]     self._set_parameters(
[ntrip_ros.py-1]   File "/opt/ros/galactic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rclpy/node.py", line 736, in _set_parameters
[ntrip_ros.py-1]     raise InvalidParameterTypeException(
[ntrip_ros.py-1] rclpy.exceptions.InvalidParameterTypeException: Trying to set parameter 'username' to '12345' of type 'INTEGER', expecting type 'STRING'
[ERROR] [ntrip_ros.py-1]: process has died [pid 702095, exit code 1, cmd '/home/vrichard/test/install/ntrip_client/lib/ntrip_client/ntrip_ros.py --ros-args -r __node:=ntrip_client_node -r __ns:=/ntrip_client --params-file /tmp/launch_params_cmiltczq'].
```

I don't think the launch file is doing any weird thing. The 'username' parameter is just declared with a default string value: https://github.com/LORD-MicroStrain/ntrip_client/blob/ros2-1.2.0/launch/ntrip_client_launch.py#L16

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/406180/how-to-specify-launch-argument-type-in-ros2-launch-command?/) by [vrichard](https://answers.ros.org/users/36745/vrichard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2022-09-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@shonigmann was close to the actual answer. It is possible to force the value to be intepreted as string by surrounding the param:=value pair with quotes *and* surrounding the value itself aswell. Like so:

```
ros2 launch ntrip_client ntrip_client_launch.py "username:='12345'"
```

---

Originally posted by [vrichard](https://answers.ros.org/users/36745/vrichard/) with karma: 108 on 2022-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So the error actually appears to be due to a `Node` expecting a `Parameter` of a string type, and something is getting lost in the `Argument`/`LaunchConfiguration` -> `Parameter` conversion.

You can force the launch system to interpret the argument as a String type by surrounding the `name:=value` pair in quotes as suggested in the [node arguments docs](https://docs.ros.org/en/galactic/How-To-Guides/Node-arguments.html), e.g. `ros2 launch my_pkg launch.py "username:=12345"`

---

Originally posted by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) with karma: 1567 on 2022-09-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vrichard](https://answers.ros.org/users/36745/vrichard/) on 2022-09-10**:
Thank you for the feedback. Surrounding the pair with quotes does not change anything. The 12345 value is still interpreted as integer and the node fails to run. I have updated the description to give a reproducible example.